# Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(project)

Tags: angular, typescript, migration, angular5, angular6

After migrating application from angular 5 to 6, on running ng serve the following errors pop up.

> Schema validation failed with the following errors:
>     Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(project).
>   Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
>     Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(project).
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._registry.compile.pipe.operators_1.concatMap.validatorResult [as project] (.../TemplateApp/me-cmf-web-template-angular/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/workspace/workspace.js:210:42)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (/.../me-cmf-web-template-angular/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:65:27)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._next (.../me-cmf-web-template-angular/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:55:18)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/home/training/Attinad_Projects/TemplateApp/me-cmf-web-template-angular/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:64:18)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (.../TemplateApp/me-cmf-web-template-angular/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:84:26)
>       at InnerSubscriber._next (.../me-cmf-web-template-angular/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/InnerSubscriber.js:25:21)
>       at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/.../me-cmf-web-template-angular/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:64:18)
>       at MapSubscriber._next (.../me-cmf-web-template-angular/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/map.js:52:26)
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/.../me-cmf-web-template-angular/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:64:18)
>       at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (.../me-cmf-web-template-angular/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:77:26)

I assume that the error is with .angular.json file which I re-named from .angular-cli.json .

My .angular.json file is as follows :

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "project": {
        "name": "mediaweb"
    },
    "apps": [{
            "root": "src",
            "outDir": "dist/browser",
            "assets": [
                "assets",
                "favicon.ico"
            ],
            "index": "index.html",
            "main": "main.ts",
            "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
            "test": "test.ts",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "prefix": "app",
            "styles": [
                "styles.scss",
                "../node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css",
                "../node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css",
                "../node_modules/video.js/dist/video-js.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
                "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
                "../node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.js",
                "../node_modules/video.js/dist/ie8/videojs-ie8.js",
                "../node_modules/video.js/dist/video.js"
            ],
            "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
            "environments": {
                "dev": "environments/environment.dev.ts",
                "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
        },
        {
            "platform": "server",
            "root": "src",
            "outDir": "dist/server",
            "assets": [
                "assets",
                "favicon.ico"
            ],
            "index": "index.html",
            "main": "main.server.ts",
            "test": "test.ts",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
            "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "prefix": "app",
            "styles": [
                "styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
            "environments": {
                "dev": "environments/environment.dev.ts",
                "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
        }
    ],
    "e2e": {
        "protractor": {
            "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
        }
    },
    "lint": [{
            "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**", "**/UI/**"]
        },
        {
            "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
        },
        {
            "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
        }
    ],
    "test": {
        "karma": {
            "config": "./karma.conf.js"
        }
    },
    "defaults": {
        "styleExt": "scss",
        "component": {}
    }
}
```

Should I re-structure the json file, if so how?.

Any help would be great.

Comment: This is not angular.json structure, you something missed while upgrading.... create new fresh project and compare angular.json file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since I fixed the issue I thought it would be nice to post it here.

I changed my file name .angular.json to angular.json and replaced some properties from the question in it.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/workspace/workspace-schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "template-appv6": {
      "root": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "favicon.ico",
                "input": "src",
                "output": "/"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "template-appv6:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "template-appv6:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "template-appv6:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "favicon.ico",
                "input": "src",
                "output": "/"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/server",
            "main": "src/main.server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "template-appv6-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "cli": {},
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "template-appv6:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {},
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "css"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

I changed the file by replacing the angular.json file with properties in the angular official docs.

The official [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/) provides a step by step guide on how to update versions.

Answer (score 59):

The issue is generally because of a version mismatch in your `package.json` file.

In my Angular 7 app, I have changed `"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.2"` to `"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0"`.

Then I ran the command `npm install` after deleting `node_modules`.

Aside: Use `^` carefully. Your working code may not work in the future if there is a major change in the package used.

Using the same package-lock.json file will also do the magic.

Comment: It also worked for me thanks. Any idea why it was not working with version 0.800.2?

Comment: I guess it's because of a major version mismatch

Comment: @Sasikumar I've been following this and several other similar pieces of advice to correct version mismatch.  Each version change I make just gives different errors.  How does one get to the bottom of version mismatches?  Isn't there something in the libraries that tells npm which versions to install?

Comment: The official document is itself clear. U can refer,https://angular.io/cli/update. Angular itself is providing update guides. I think it will be more helpful, https://update.angular.io/

Comment: @mike_butak  Try like this, Revery your code to the runnable stage. Then start updating the package one after the other. It will be easy to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Sasikumar Thanks, Deleting node_modules and running `npm i` fixed this for me. my issue was I have two branches, one of them have an updated angular version.

Comment: @Sasikumar Thanks . I have faced the issued in angular 17. Error  Data path "" must have required property 'browserTarget'. After deleting the node_modules and running npm i. fixed my issue .

Answer (score 32):

my app is on angular 7.2.3

remove  "es5BrowserSupport": true from angular.json.
and npm start now works.

Comment: es5BrowserSupport at true is a very good idea to increase performances on the first load. Disabling it is not a solution...

Comment: you have to remove `es5BrowserSupport`, it is no more allowed to use this key within `angular.json`  (Angular ^v10)

Answer (score 22):

just go to the angular.json file and remove

> "extractCss": true

on the

> production section.

Answer (score 20):

When i was getting version error issues,Following command worked for me:

First run:

```
npm update
```

Second run:

```
ng update
```

Third run:
(It will update all the mismatching packages)

```
npm update --all --force
```

Comment: `ng update --all --force` wth error `Error: Unknown argument: all`

Comment: `ng update --all --force` is a typo. This answer should be updated to `npm update --all --force`.

Answer (score 15):

First:

```
npm uninstall @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

Next:

```
npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.12.4
```

Answer (score 10):

Angular Upgrade from 9 to 10 is very easy (all additional detail-information is here: https://update.angular.io/?v=9.0-10.0) :

> Make sure your package file is in version control and all changes have been committed. This will overwrite your package file. Better you try it in a new experimental branch.

```sh
npm install -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
ng update --all --force
```

In the new schema, it is no longer allowed to use the key `es5BrowserSupport`; remove the following line in your `angular.json`:

```
"es5BrowserSupport": true
```

then simply start your application anew:

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 6):

Change `package.json` from:

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.5",
```

to:

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.1",
```

Answer (score 3):

the format of **angular.json** needs to be as per Angular6... You can check my angular.json below or create a new project in Angular6 and then check the format of the 'project' head

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "homePage6": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/homePage6",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.json"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "serviceWorker": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "homePage6:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "homePage6:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "homePage6:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.json"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "homePage6-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "homePage6:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "homePage6"
}
```

I ran into similar (not identical, but also in angular.json) issue:

> Schema validation failed with the following errors:   Data path
>   "['server']" should NOT have additional properties(scripts). Error:
>   Schema validation failed with the following errors:   Data path
>   "['server']" should NOT have additional properties(scripts).
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._registry.compile.pipe.operators_1.concatMap.validatorResult
>   [as project]
>   (D:\Angular7\uHome\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\src\workspace\workspace.js:215:42)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (D:\Angular7\uHome\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:69:27)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._next (D:\Angular7\uHome\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:59:18)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (D:\Angular7\uHome\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (D:\Angular7\uHome\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:92:26)
>       at InnerSubscriber._next (D:\Angular7\uHome\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
>       at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (D:\Angular7\uHome\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
>       at MapSubscriber._next (D:\Angular7\uHome\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\map.js:55:26)
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (D:\Angular7\uHome\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
>       at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (D:\Angular7\uHome\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:86:26)

had to remove the property scripts from my angular.json... sharing this information to help someone in the future.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me; removing the property script solved my issue

Answer (score 3):

When upgrading `Angular` from version `8` to `10` I got very similar error, namely `Schema validation failed with the following errors:   Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(serverTarget).`.

The solution was remove all `"serverTarget"` references from below `"serve"`. The below was **wrong**:

```
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "options": {
    "browserTarget": "my_app:build"
    "serverTarget": "my_app:server"
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "browserTarget": "my_app:build:production",
      "serverTarget": "my_app:server:production"
    }
  }
},
```

The below is **correct** and **compiled successfully**:

```
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "options": {
    "browserTarget": "my_app:build"
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "browserTarget": "my_app:build:production"
    }
  }
},
```

**Bonus** for those who are working with `Angular Universal`. If you want to run SSR on `localhost`, then indeed you need the `serverTarget`. However, for that you have to create a new section within the `angular.json`, something like:

```
"serve-ssr": {
  "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
  "options": {
    "browserTarget": "my_app:build",
    "serverTarget": "my_app:server"
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "browserTarget": "my_app:build:production",
      "serverTarget": "my_app:server:production"
    }
  }
},
```

Then `ng run my_app:serve-ssr`.

Actually I got this error when upgrading `Angular` from version `10` into `8` and wanted to improve some things. Then I've messed up the `serverTarget` thing with that wrong thinking, hopefully this will help out someone with `Angular Universal` in a project.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's with `RxJS`'s incompatibility. You should install `rxjs-compat` to fix this.

```
npm install rxjs-compat
```

Also, the name of the file is `angular.json` and not `.angular.json`

Comment: installed rxjs-compat are re-run ng serve, the same issue persists. I used https://update.angular.io/  , this documentation to migrate.

Answer (score 2):

Updating `npm` and `angular` fixed mine:

Assuming you use `npm`

```
npm update
```

then run:

```
ng update
```

NB: You might be prompted to update individual dependencies. In my case, I was prompted to run:

`ng update @angular/cli` and `ng update @angular/core`.

Answer (score 2):

This error also shows when we add some properties that are not supported in the angular.json configuration

The Angular application we create must be listed under the `projects` properties  (with a 's'), but in this case it is under `project`

The top level properties are listed [here](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config)

Answer (score 1):

go to `package.json` and change the version of **@angular-devkit/build-angular** as follows:

`@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.4"`

Answer (score 1):

Remove these two lines from the angular.json file:

```
"vendorSourceMap":"true",
"evalSourceMap":"true".
```

Answer (score 1):

###### removing the flag `es5BrowserSupport: true` from `angular.json` fixed the problem.

Since I was updating from `Angular7` to `Angular11`, I skipped a point from https://update.angular.io/ upgrade guide.

###### Remove any `es5BrowserSupport flags in your angular.json` and set your `target to es2015 in your tsconfig.json`. Angular now uses your browserslist to determine if an ES5 build is needed. ng update will migrate you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the **node_module** folder and run

> NPM Install

and it worked fine for me.

It is an **Angular 9** solution.

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything that are written above, it still didn't work.
Until, I rebooted my system.
Add this to your last resort.

- Reboot system

Answer (score 0):

just remove node_modules and do `npm i` sometimes some packages don't compile well, when you switch from one version to another version

Answer (score 0):

please check your "angular/cli" version in "package.json", the version number must be similar to other angular packages.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.29",
     "@angular/cli": "~13.2.2", (this is the wrong one)
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
```

Answer (score 0):

In my project I was using a relative import in one of the files to another library outside the scope of ng-packagr (../another-lib). After changing to a module import (@scope/another-lib) it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced this issue, and it was because I added "basehref" in the angular.json  section, which I think is not more supported, removed it, & it worked. & if anyone is troubled to add a root basehref into an angular app, you may need to do like below:-

1. import this <import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common'> in app.module.ts
2. & then in the module  array, add this as object into the list <{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/your-root-url/'}>

Answer (score 0):

In my case in Angular 16 beta version, I added tsConfig to `architect > build > options` like this:
`"tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json"`

In most cases, the CLI added stuff like this but in my case, it wasn't there.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue with Angular 16 .
after doing ng add @nguniversal/express-engine projectname fix the issue (ex.ng add @nguniversal/express-engine angularuniversalapp)
initially i was trying ng add @nguniversal/express-engine clientProjectName project name so facing issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this problem, I made a project with `single-spa-angular`, when creating the angular app itself it worked correctly, but when adding single-spa and single-spa-angular to the project it stopped working, I was installing versions of angular different but the error was not fixed, until I started to review the `angular.json`, and compared it with other projects that I have, I found that when installing single-spa, it made changes to this file, it had added another **"main"** in **"build"**.

I solved it in the following way:

1. Remove `"browser": "src/main.ts",`

[image]

2. pass the main where we delete the browser

[image]

Emphasize that I had this problem because I installed single-spa, if you have not installed it, check that the main is not being referenced elsewhere, that is, it has to be within options