# ng serve -o command is not working after installing jquery

Tags: jquery, angular

I had install jquery in the angular using following command

```
 $ npm install jquery --save
```

After this when i tried to open the localhost for angular using the following command :

```
  ng serve -o
```

Then it shows me following errors, please see the following image

[image]

Please guide me to resolve this issue.

Comment: have you tried without -o flag

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari Sir, Yes I have tried without -o flag, it shows the same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(project)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52398449/error-schema-validation-failed-with-the-following-errors-data-path-should-n)