# Angular build and server opening

Tags: angular

I try to work on an Angular application whose setup precedes me (certain trouble). After angular-cli installation on local machine by commands below, I run "sudo ng serve -o". The first error log appears below. The suggested solutions were the update of angular cli and build angular or comment the line "es5BrowserSupport": true on angular.json . Only the latter changed the prior log.

```
>> sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
// Installation log ommitted

>> ng serve -o
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(es5BrowserSupport).

>> sudo ng update @angular/cli
>> sudo ng update @angular-devkit/build-angular

>> ng serve -o 
An unhandled exception occurred: Job name "..getProjectMetadata" does not exist.
See "/tmp/ng-Q6e3Kl/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

After research through foruns, the common solution was to downgrade the build-angular by typing the following command.

```
>> npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.24
// Installation log ommitted

>> ng serve --o
An unhandled exception occurred: Job name "..getProjectMetadata" does not exist.
See "/tmp/ng-R1gyui/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

I can't proceed further. Any help is appreciated and if needed, I can provide additional information.

Best regards,
Bruno Peixoto

Comment: Do you mean `ng serve --o` maybe? If not please explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you. I editted the post.

Comment: Maybe this answer solves your problem, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56492948/8842959

Comment: Unfortunately not.